# Is there a hierarchical list component for Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, list

I will implement this myself if I can't find it but after 30 minutes of searching on the web I'm a bit surprised this doesn't exist.  Basically what I need is a hierarchical list component like the finder app on mac.  I want the same functionality as a tree component but displayed as each level having it's own list resulting in multiple lists that depend on each other.  Is the work already done for me?

Thanks!

Comment: I've only seen one; and it was in a private app.  I don't know of any open source (or commercial) implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve your required functionality using [AdvancedDataGrid](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/AdvancedDataGrid.html)

few samples are

- [About the AdvancedDataGrid
  control](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=advdatagrid_02.html)
- [Tree in Advanced DataGrid
  Example](http://www.flex-blog.com/tree-in-advanced-datagrid-example/)
- [Navigation Tree icon and labels in
  AdvancedDataGrid](http://www.roseindia.net/software-tutorials/detail/1320)

Hopes that helps

Imran

Comment: It doesn't seem to support one column of data being dependent on the selection of another column.  Sure you could hack it but at that point you might as well use 2 List components since a datagrid is not really the proper structure anyway.